# Is ML Kit Face Detection on-device free for commercial companies usage?

Tags: firebase, google-mlkit

I've founded the ML Kit on-device and use it in my company new project and it is working fine but I need to know if there is any payment could be required when the app's will be  uploaded on the stores(android and IOS markets), I will use only the offline version in the project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The on-device versions of ML Kit are no longer part of Firebase, and are now known as Google ML Kit. They are free and unlimited, and you will not be charged for using them.

From the [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/guides) documentation:

> All are powered by Google's best-in-class ML models and offered to you at no cost.

Comment: That's great to hear